# JS issue while assigning .split() result to a variable called 'name'

Tags: javascript

I was making some tests with the JS's `split()` string method in Firefox's console. While testing I did the following:

```
test = 'first second third'.split(' ')
-> Array [ "first", "second", "third" ]
test
-> Array [ "first", "second", "third" ]
name = 'first second third'.split(' ')
-> Array [ "first", "second", "third" ]
name
-> "first,second,third"
```

I noticed that everytime I called the `split()` method it returned an `Array` but if I saved it in a variable called `name` then it was saved as a `string` rather than an `Array`.

Why does this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, as the commenters have correctly pointed out, this is not about `Function.name`, but `window.name`.

Nice catch, the comment above is partially right, `name` is not a reserved word but it can cause problems because it is one of the predefined names of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties. Perhaps it should have been a reserved word.

Source: [Reserved words...](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

Specifically it is part of the `window` object.

```
__proto__ Property Names in Object Initializers:
If IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition(AssignmentExpression) is true, then
Let hasNameProperty be HasOwnProperty(propValue, "name").
ReturnIfAbrupt(hasNameProperty).
If hasNameProperty is false, perform SetFunctionName(propValue, propKey).
```

Here are the relevant steps: [Spec for name](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname)

```
SetFunctionName (F, name, prefix)
If Type(name) is Symbol, then
Let description be name’s [[Description]] value.
If description is undefined, let name be the empty String.
Else, let name be the concatenation of "[", description, and "]".
```

Note the last else, where 'name' will be concatenated into a string.

Comment: _“Everything you set to name will be a string!”_ – if this was really about `Function.name`, then you could not “set” anything to it, because as you quoted, _“This property has the attributes { **[[Writable]]: false**”_

Comment: _“Note when you just type in name without doing anything else in the console, it returns an empty string”_ – only if the window object didn’t get a name set (granted, that would be the case most of the time, since we left framesets behind us …). But create a simple document containing `<a href="http://example.com/" target="foobar">click me</a>`, click that link – and then in the new window it opens, type `name` into the console again … "foobar"

Answer (score 2):

This issue will only come from `window.name`, due to the way it's [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and/or [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) is defined. If you use the variable `name` inside a function, you won't face this issue.

In case you're curious to see how `window.name` changes the output from the array to a string, here is a quick example I made: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0qha3v5/1/).

Comment: WTF did this get downvoted? (+1 from me, to even that out.) It is more correct than the accepted answer – because this is not about functions, but the window object and its name property.

Comment: And a good time to plug `strict mode` and making sure one always declares one's variables.

Answer (score 2):

To add to JordanHendrix’ answer, and be a little more specific:

`name` here is [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name) – a property every window object has, which is mainly used in combination with the `target` attribute on links or forms.

And because that property only accepts a string value, your array that split returns has to be converted back to a string value. That happens by implicitly calling its [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method – and what that method does, is joining all the array values together, separated by commas.